# Compile Time Error

Tags: exception

Please tell me that What actually happening here-- Actually compile time error is here but why ?

```
public class A
{ 
   static int test(String s1)
   {
      try { 
         return 1;
      }
      catch(NumberFormatException e){ 
         return 2; 
      }
      return 3;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please check the formatting help and format your code as code. Also, tag your post with the language. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and show the error.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess this is Java. It will probably complain that you are not using the argument `s1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try { 
   return 1;
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){ 
   return 2; 
}
```

...will always return 1 (or 2 if the try could throw that exception), so your statement...

```
return 3;
```

...is always unreachable and will give a compile error.